# Android custom CheckableImageButton not working correctly

Tags: android

I want to use widget as `CheckableImageButton` on my application, but this code, image state not working correctly when I click on image that state must be changed

always I get true after change state

```
public class CheckableImageButton extends ImageButton implements Checkable {

    private boolean mChecked;
    private boolean mBroadcasting;
    private int mPersonality;
    private OnCheckedChangeListener mOnCheckedChangeListener;

    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = { R.attr.is_checked };

    private static final int PERSONALITY_RADIO_BUTTON = 0;
    private static final int PERSONALITY_CHECK_BOX = 1;

    public CheckableImageButton(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CheckableImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CheckableImageButton);

        mPersonality = a.getInt(R.styleable.CheckableImageButton_personality, PERSONALITY_RADIO_BUTTON);
        boolean checked = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CheckableImageButton_is_checked, false);
        setChecked(checked);

        a.recycle();
    }

    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        if (mPersonality == PERSONALITY_RADIO_BUTTON) {
            setChecked(true);
        } else if (mPersonality == PERSONALITY_CHECK_BOX) {
            toggle();
        }
        return super.performClick();
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * Changes the checked state of this button.
     * </p>
     *
     * @param checked
     *            true to check the button, false to uncheck it
     */
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        if (mChecked != checked) {
            mChecked = checked;
            refreshDrawableState();

            // Avoid infinite recursions if setChecked() is called from a listener
            if (mBroadcasting) {
                return;
            }

            mBroadcasting = true;
            if (mOnCheckedChangeListener != null) {
                mOnCheckedChangeListener.onCheckedChanged(this, mChecked);
            }

            mBroadcasting = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register a callback to be invoked when the checked state of this button changes.
     *
     * @param listener
     *            the callback to call on checked state change
     */
    public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener listener) {
        mOnCheckedChangeListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Interface definition for a callback.
     */
    public static interface OnCheckedChangeListener {
        /**
         * Called when the checked state of a button has changed.
         *
         * @param button
         *            The button view whose state has changed.
         * @param isChecked
         *            The new checked state of button.
         */
        void onCheckedChanged(CheckableImageButton button, boolean isChecked);
    }

    @Override
    public int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        }
        return drawableState;
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();
        invalidate();
    }

    static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
        boolean checked;

        SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        private SavedState(Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            checked = (Boolean) in.readValue(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
            out.writeValue(checked);
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new SavedState(in);
            }

            public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);
        ss.checked = isChecked();
        return ss;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;

        super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
        setChecked(ss.checked);
        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

`checkable_image_selector` file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="4dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#FFFFC700"
        android:centerColor="#FFFFA600"
        android:endColor="#FFFFC700" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#FF80B0E0" />
</shape>
```

and `checkable_image_button_state_pressed`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="4dp"/>
    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp"/>
    <solid
        android:color="#00000000"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#FF80B0E0"/>
</shape>
```

and then i use that like with this code:

```
checkable_image_1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckableImageButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CheckableImageButton button, boolean isChecked) {
        Log.e("CHECK: ", isChecked + "");
        checkable_image_1.setChecked(false);
    }
});
checkable_image_1.setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CheckableImageButton extends AppCompatImageButton implements Checkable {

private static final int[] DRAWABLE_STATE_CHECKED = new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked};

private boolean mChecked;

public CheckableImageButton(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CheckableImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.imageButtonStyle);
}

public CheckableImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(this, new AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View host, AccessibilityEvent event) {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(host, event);
            event.setChecked(isChecked());
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host,
                AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat info) {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
            info.setCheckable(true);
            info.setChecked(isChecked());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    if (mChecked != checked) {
        mChecked = checked;
        refreshDrawableState();
        sendAccessibilityEvent(
                AccessibilityEventCompat.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isChecked() {
    return mChecked;
}

@Override
public void toggle() {
    setChecked(!mChecked);
}

@Override
public int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
    if (mChecked) {
        return mergeDrawableStates(
                super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + DRAWABLE_STATE_CHECKED.length),
                DRAWABLE_STATE_CHECKED);
    } else {
        return super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace);
    }
}
```

}